# remove decimal from "Order Summary" email template

Tags: magento-1.9

How to remove decimal from "Order Summary" email template?
The Order Summary box is rendered from this email template line:

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick and dirty solution to edit the core files.
On class Mage_Sales_Model_Order

edit:

```
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 2, $addBrackets); // replace 2 with 0
}
```

of course there should be a better way to do this, using rewrite.